# xcodebuild fails on Travis CI with exit code 70

Tags: ios, open-source, travis-ci, xcodebuild

I'm running into an issue with my Xcode project build with Travis CI.

Here's the build: https://travis-ci.org/codytwinton/SwiftyVIPER

I'm getting this issue:

```
xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
    { OS:10.0, name:iPhone 5 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I know this was a while back. Did you have find a solution?

Comment: @D.Greg yes, check the project. Seems to be running now.

Comment: Do you remember what your solution was?

Comment: @D.Greg - Honestly, I don't exactly remember. However, if you copy my `.travis.yml`, and merely change a few details to link with your project, you should be able to get up and running.

Comment: I got my problem sorted out. I ended up using one of the simulator ids for the key value pair. Thanks for responding.